# create function my.render.cat with comma decimal separator instead of point in r

Tags: r, html-table, decimal, separator

I am trying to create a function to get frequencies and proportions for a table1 with this code

`my.render.cat <- function(x) { c("", sapply(stats.default(x), function(y) with(y, sprintf("%d (%0.0f %%)", FREQ, PCT)))) }`

but when I apply it to the function table1() I get the results for proportions with decimal point instead of comma.

I've tried with `options(OutDec= ",")` but nothing changes
Nor by changing Sys.locale for LC NUMERIC.

I've also tried with `format(table1, decimal.mark=",")` but it doesn't work for table1 output

any suggestions?

I add a reproducible example using iris dataset and formatting Sepal.length to be able to calculate proportions.

`table1::table1(~factor(Sepal.Length) | Species, data = iris, render.categorical=my.render.cat)`

Comment: try library `scales`, you can use function `number()`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I've edited the post to create a reproducible example

Comment: very sory again. `table1()` function is from "table1" package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` to replace `.` with `,`.

```
library(table1)

my.render.cat <- function(x) { 
  sub('.', ',', c("", sapply(stats.default(x), 
  function(y) with(y, sprintf("%d (%0.2f %%)", FREQ, PCT)))), fixed = TRUE) 
}

table1(~factor(Sepal.Length) | Species, data = iris, 
       render.categorical=my.render.cat)
```